# Extract int array from C file

Tags: java, c, parsing

I'm developing a little Java software to decode specific data from another system.

This system can only extract data in a *.c file :

```
    /* Frame (574 bytes) */
static const unsigned char pkt22[574] = {
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc1, 0x2f, /* ......./ */
0x48, 0x00, 0x10, 0x27, 0x40, 0x00, 0x3e, 0x00, /* H..'y.>. */
...
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc1, 0xd6, /* ........ */
0xac, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 /* ........ */
};

/* Frame (574 bytes) */
static const unsigned char pkt59[574] = {
0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x17, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
...
0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x68, 0x40, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, /* ...h@..h */
0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 /* @....... */
};
```

I want to extract this data and use it in my Java software.
Is there a parser that can help me do that ?

Comment: It could be a use-case for a simple regex. Just catch the declaration you want, then extract between the next `{ }`

Comment: Thanks Jakob, simple and efficient.
I'll give you the feedback

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
int pkt22[] = new int[] {
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc1, 0x2f, /* ......./ */
   ...
};

int pkt59[] = new int[] {
   0x00, 0xC2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, /* ........ */
   ...
};
```

using copy-paste?

Comment: Simple and effective way, but the questioner asked for a parser.

Comment: The .c file is supposed to be an input for the software. That's why the "copy/paste" is not the best way for me.